# How Can we achieve audio recording pause/resume functionality in android 4.0

Tags: android

I am working on one small android application.With in that I have a requirement like audio recording with pause and resume options.I searched a lot in the Google,but I couldn't get anything related to that.

Somebody said that there is no default pause and resume functionality in android.

If you want that ,"you need to save that recorded audio file while click on pause button and save into your SD card.And you need to start again from the beginning when you click on resume button.At lost If you want to upload ,then you need to merge all the recorded files as one file then upload it".

I followed his suggestion,but there is no such related code for merging audio files of m4a format available in java/android.

Can anyone suggest me on this.

Comment: You can use [ffmpeg library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg4android/) to merge media files.

Answer (score 1):

yes that's correct android audio recorder don't support pause you need to stop and start this 
and merge all the files together to create a recording

You need to use the audiorecorder class the good example is here 
[Android : recording audio using audiorecord class play as fast forwarded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862662/android-recording-audio-using-audiorecord-class-play-as-fast-forwarded)

and you need to merge them as demostrated here

[Merging pcm audio files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161231/merging-pcm-audio-files)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.But this one is not worked for me.

Comment: Can anyone give other solutions for my requirement.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually when I follow this procedure, the file size is getting increased. But the length of the file (i.e. in time) is not increasing and hence when I play the resultant file I can hear only the 1st recording.

Comment: @Aashish Bhatnagar : I used this but it take more time to merge audio with video so i need another solution.if you found then update here.